# javascript effect only works on the first element but not on others?

Tags: php, html, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am echoing records from the database which are wrapped with html tags and was trying to put some effect on the echoed data. When I click the edit link, the textfield should shake. It works on the first element but when I click the edit link of the next element, the first textfield still shakes and not the other one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Wallpost</title>
<style>

    .wallpost input[type="text"]{
        width: 500px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .wallpost input[type="submit"]{
        height: 26px;
    }


    .user{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .post{
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';



$user = $_SESSION['user'];; 

echo '<form action="post.php" method="post" class="wallpost"><input 
type="text" name="post" size="50"><input type="submit" name="wallpost" 
value="Post"></form>';

$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM statuspost ORDER BY id DESC");

while($i = $query->fetch_object()){
    //echo $i->post.'  '.$i->id.' <a href="wallpost.php?type=post&
id='.$i->id.'" >Remove</a>'.'<br/>';
    echo '<span class="user">'.$i->user.'</span>'.'<br>'.'<span 
class="post">'.$i->post.'</span>'.' <form action="editpost.php?type=post&
id='.$i->id.'" method="post"><span id="edit"><input type="text"  
name="edit">
<br/><input type="submit" value="Edit"></span><a href="#" 
onclick="showEdit();">Edit </a><a href="remove.php?type=post&
id='.$i->id.'" >Remove</a></form> '.'<br/><br/>';
    //echo '<div id="post">'.$i->post.'  '.$i->id.'<a href="#" 
id="anchor" class="',$i->id,'" onclick="del();">Remove</a></div>  
<br/>';     

}


?>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0
/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0
/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script>

 function showEdit(){

    Effect.Shake('edit');
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have duplicate ID's, they need to be unique.

Comment: Is there a way to make them unique? Since I only concatenated the html tags with the echoed records because the records might be added and it's too hard to keep track of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<span id="edit">` by something like `<span id="edit'.$i->id.'">` to have different ids on each elements. Then of course, `showEdit()` must know which id it has to shake, so it has to take a parameter. Or even simpler: replace `onclick="showEdit();"` by `onclick="Effect.Shake(\'edit'.$i->id.'\');"`

Comment: Hi, I wanna know how can I instantiate the parameter because scriptaculous does not seem to take classes as attributes, only id. I'm trying to get the attribute of the span tag but only id is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptaculous effects take either an ID or a JavaScript reference to a DOM element as their first argument, so if you add a classname to your multiple elements, you can shake all of them at once like this:

```
<span class="shake-me">...</span>
<span class="shake-me">...</span>
<span class="shake-me">...</span>
```

Inside an enumerator:

```
$$('.shake-me').each(function(elm){
  Effect.Shake(elm);
});
```